# Integrity Error on Django ForeignKey relations

Tags: sql, django, django-models

I have three django models related by Foreign keys as shown below

```
class Table1(models.Model):
...

class Table2(models.Model):
    table1 = models.ForeignKey("Table1", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="rel_table2")


class Table3(models.Model):
    table2 = models.ForeignKey("Table2", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, default=None, related_name="rel_table3")
```

So in essence, each Table1 object has one or more Table2 objects and each table 2 object also has one or more Table3 objects.

When I delete a Table1 object, I expect the related Table2 and Table 3 to be cascade-deleted. But instead I get an Integrity error

`IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed`

unless I first delete in order the related Table3 and Table2 objects.

(Same for when I delete a Table2 object -I'm only able to delete it when I delete manually all the related Table3 objects)

Am I doing something wrong?

(I am using Django 3.2)

I changed the Table3 model by removing the options `null=True` and `default=None` as shown below

```
class Table3(models.Model):
    table2 = models.ForeignKey("Table2", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="rel_table3")
```

and the cascading delete works for this. But that is unexpected.

Why does it work?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this on Django 3.2 with SQLite and PostgreSQL. Can you show a test case for a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Ooh that's right. I created a Django project from scratch and created the same relations and the cascade delete works well. Does this mean it's a problem with my original database? And is there a way I can still resolve it?

Comment: Well, without a minimal, reproducible example, there is simply insufficient information to answer that.